# I am using a Hostinger VPS cloudhost to host a django Backend , everything working fine while hosting IP address and port but not in domain?

Tags: django, cross-domain, hosting, ip-address, cross-domain-proxy

Hosting Problem
[Its showing like this , But in IP address its is working fine all the images are fetching from backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD66G.png)...
[See this also coming like this but its working in IP address with port its working fine ,while in domain its not working or posting the  form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iol2X.png)

if i check the hosting method its working fine but its not working good in my domain ,do i have to change something in server conf file

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add your domain in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS.

Just add the domain in CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in your settings file like this.

For django 4 and above

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://yourdomain.com']
```

For django 3 and lower version, no need to mention scheme

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['yourdomain.com']
```

Read here to get further details : [CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins)

Comment: Thank you for help its working but still django style are not working

Comment: what's the error, can you share screen shot of network logs on browser